# OpenTelemetry for Envoy traces

Tags: envoyproxy, open-telemetry

Has anyone got Envoy traces working with OpenTelemetry collector? I'd be very appreciative if you could share how that's done. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need a collector with a Zipkin or jaeger receiver.
We set it up on istio that uses envoy under the hood, but it was straightforward; all we had to do on the istio side was point it to the collector DNS at the correct port.
we used a Zipkin receiver at the default port (`9411`)

Answer (score 0):

To send spans to the OTEL collector you can make use of multiple tracers, using envoy. Like OpenCensus, Jaeger, Zipkin ... which can be configured against an OTEL collector.

The more important part is to be W3C compliant, therefore you currently have to use the OpenCensus tracer. So you can combine an OpenCensus tracer, sending data to an OpenTelemetry collector. [Here](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/9958#issuecomment-981428952) you can find example config.

In future envoy proxies will most likely directly support OTEL tracers.